# how to write a type of array that value is only part of key of object in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I have a type like following how can I write a type for a array that the element of array can only be part of key?

```
type InputType = {
  name: string;
  phone: string;
  num: number;
  numRun: number;
  numEdit: number;
  posiRun: number;
  posiEdit: number;
}

const preferArray = ['name', 'num', 'numRun']
const preferArray = ['name', 'num', 'numRun', 'abc'] // should complain the error because abc is not part of key from InputType
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `(keyof InputType)[]`:

```
const preferArray: (keyof InputType)[] = ['name', 'num', 'numRun'] // works
const preferArray1: (keyof InputType)[] = ['name', 'num', 'numRun', 'abc'] // error
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdmArsAKuaBeKBvAUFKOAQwFsIAuKAZ2ACcBLOAcwG58owALAezgurqNW7OIhKVRJAEYRabApIBKiOBLEy5IsQFEAJvWBrps+R25V6y1YXUn2Yc-T0GjGtgF9cuAMa8aHWggAM1kAQVpaIhBKAAoAawgQbiDYBGQ0SABKAG0AXSgsbIByYjIigBooErEKqqUVItyfP2AA4LCIqIBGWISklPgkVHQc-MKS0gha6pJp+rhpoilvRqggA)